# react-data-table-component - Checkboxes won't stay checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, checkbox, react-data-table-component

I am having a problem in [react-data-table-component](https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component) where the checkboxes in my datatable don't remain "checked".

I do see there is indication the check occurred but not seeing it remaining checked:
[image]

It's weird, right?  Why is that happening?

Here's my code:

```
             <DataTable
                 title={ `Items` }
                 columns={ columns }
                 data={ filteredItems }
                 pagination
                 paginationResetDefaultPage={ resetPaginationToggle_users }
                 subHeader
                 onRowClicked={ handleRowClicked }
                 selectableRows
                 selectableRowsComponent={Checkbox} // Pass the function only
                 selectableRowsComponentProps={selectProps}
                 onSelectedRowsChange={ handleSelectedRows }
                 responsive
                 expandableRows
                 expandOnRowClicked
                 expandableRowsHideExpander
                 expandableRowsComponent={ <UpdateItemComponent data={ mainData } s={ s } setS={ setS } /> }
                 persistTableHead
             />
```

Perhaps it's something to do with `selectableRowsComponent` and `Checkbox`?

Here's how that is being brought into this code:

```
    const Checkbox = React.forwardRef(({ onClick, ...rest }, ref) =>
    {
     return(
         <>
             <div className="form-check pb-5" style={{ backgroundColor: '' }}>
                 <input 
                     type="checkbox"
                     className="form-check-input"
                     style={{ height: '20px', width: '20px' }}
                     ref={ref}
                     onClick={ onClick }
                     {...rest}
                 />
                 <label className="form-check-label" id="booty-check" />
             </div>
         </>
     )
    })
```

I am trying to have the checkboxes remain checked.

How to do it?

Comment: Please share a bit more of the code i.e. where are props like `selectProps` coming from? I smell JavaScript falsy behavior at play here ... It might be that somewhere there is an if statement that checks `if (checkedRowIndex)` in such a case JavaScript will mark the condition as false if checkedRowIndex === 0 ... Please note this `checkedRowIndex` is just something I made up to try to explain what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just had exactly same problem.

It was because the [`useEffect`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect#useeffect) hook was missing a dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Some code
});
```

I just added `[]` and it got solved:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Some code
}, []);
```